# How to slice a string using INSTR()

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to take the value inside the brackets ( [ ] ):
Example:

```
[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]
```

My code:

```
 select substr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]',  
           instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', '[',1,2), 
           instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', ']',1,2) )                            
      from dual
```

desired result:  `WINDOM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third parameter is length:

```
with s as (select '[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]' as Text from Dual)  

select substr(substr(s.Text, instr(s.Text, '[', 1, 2) + 1), 1, instr(substr(s.Text, instr(s.Text, '[', 1, 2) + 1), ']') - 1)                           
from s
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but `SUBSTR` has the signature `SUBSTR( string, start, length )`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1234e/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
  SELECT '[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
         value,
         open_bracket2 + 1,
         close_bracket2 - open_bracket2 - 1
       ) AS bracket2
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR( value, '[', 1, 2 ) AS open_bracket2,
         INSTR( value, ']', 1, 2 ) AS close_bracket2
  FROM   test_data
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1234e/1/0)**:

```
| BRACKET2 |
|----------|
|   WINDOM |
```